# El comando de linux ls no funciona como debería

Tags: linux, bash

Usando el comando `ls` he descubierto que hay algo que falla. Si se crea un directorio en una carpeta vacía (por ejemplo, *hola1*) y se hace un `ls hola*` no muestra nada, en cambio si creamos *hola2* y volvemos a poner el comando `ls hola*` si que muestra los dos.

[image: Aquí los comandos que utilicé]

Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto? Estoy usando un linux mint, en caso de que esta información sea relevante.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75047), en la cual se explica que en este caso quien interpreta el wildcard es el shell, no el comando `ls`. Si tú quieres que se muestre listada la carpeta, puedes indicarle a `ls` que quieres ver los directorios con algo así: `ls hola* -d`. Revisa también [esta pregunta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/571616) y sus respuestas.

Comment: lo mismo tienes un alias. Ejecuta `\ls hola*` para ejecutar el "ls" de toda la vida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de que las respuestas dadas ataquen el problema real (aunque ya hay una respuesta aceptada). El problema está en la forma en la que **bash** expande el `*` *antes* de la llamada a `ls` y cómo reacciona `ls` al haber uno o más parámetros.

Cuando solo tienes un directorio creado, y ejecutas `ls hola*`, **bash** expande la expresión `hola*` en base a lo que tiene disponible en el momento, que sería el directorio `hola1` y entonces se ejecuta `ls hola1`. Como solo pides listar lo que hay en `hola1` (y el directorio está vacío), pues no muestra nada. Luego de crear el directorio `hola2`, entonces `ls hola*` queda convertido (por **bash**) en `ls hola1 hola2` y entonces el propio `ls`, como tiene que listar lo que hay en los dos directorios, procede a colocar cada directorio antes de listar lo que hay en cada uno (que está vacío). La conducta se puede verificar si inmediatamente luego de crear `hola1`, creamos un archivo dentro y entonces ejecutamos `ls hola*`:

```
$ mkdir hola1
$ touch hola1/un-archivo
$ ls hola*
un-archivo
```

Y ahí podemos ver que `ls hola*` fue convertido por bash en `ls hola1`.

Comment: de `man ls` --> `If more than one operand is given, non-directory operands are displayed first; directory and non-directory operands are sorted separately and in lexicographical order.` Es decir, como se ve lógicamente cuando hay más de un parámetro separa las salidas para cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Wow la verdad es que esta respuesta si que me resuelve la duda del todo. Muchas gracias :D
P.D: Acepté la primera respuesta que me dieron porque estaba en clase y era la que me sirvió a priori, pero ahora he aceptado está porque es la mejor desarrollada.

Answer (score 0):

De wikipedia:

> ls archivo1 archivo2 archivo3 ... subdir1 subdir2 subdir3 ... : muestra un listado de los archivos y subdirectorios especificados en la línea de órdenes. Para los archivos muestra el nombre solamente (o más información si se emplea alguna opción como -l ) y para los subdirectorios muestra todos los archivos incluidos en el subdirectorio. Este comportamiento distinto de ls ante archivos y subdirectorios se puede igualar usando el parámetro -d, que hace que se trate a los subdirectorios como archivos. Nótese que pueden ponerse directorios y archivos en la línea de órdenes en cualquier orden.

Traducido a modo sencillo, es como que toma como referencia el argumento que le estás pasando y muestra todas las carpetas que tienen en común ese argumento.

Para tu ejemplo: Tienes 2 carpetas, `hola1` y `hola2`. Crea otras 2 carpetas que se llamen `holahola1` y `holahola2`. Ahora tienes 4 carpetas con distinto nombre, pero que tienen en común la palabra **hola**. Si tú ejecutas el comando `ls hola*` te va a mostrar todas las carpetas, porque todas empiezan por `hola`. En cambio, si ejecutas `ls holah*`, las carpetas `hola1` y `hola2` ya son distintas al argumento que has introducido en tu comando, por lo que se sólo se te visualizarán las carpetas `holahola1` y `holahola2` ya que éstas sí tienen en común el argumento que has pasado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Funciona correctamente, sólo que no tiene nada para mostrar porque tu única carpeta está vacía.

### Respuesta larga

Tengo la sospecha de que tu commando `ls` funciona correctamente, solo que te muestra su contenido que es nada.

Si le añadieras contenido a tu directorio `hola1`:

```
$ touch hola1/archivo1
```

Utilizando ese mismo comando (`ls hola*`) podrías ver que si está devolviendo algo.

Para ver que si está funcionando como debería, incluso sin contenido, trata de añadir los parámetros `-la`: `ls -la hola*`